# IOS - playing mp3 fails when moved to a separate class

Tags: ios, audio, refactoring, mp3

I successfully played an mp3 file within the body of a class. However, when I move the functionality out to a separate class, it fails.

Here's the working code:

Header:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface QuestionController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

}
```

working code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/A.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"audio errror: %@",[error description]);             
    else 
        [audioPlayer play];
```

Here's the new class:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


    @interface AudioPlayer : NSObject {

    }

    - (void *) playAudioFile:(NSString *) mp3File;

    @end
```

implementation:

```
  #import "AudioPlayer.h"

    @implementation AudioPlayer

    - (void *) playAudioFile:(NSString *) mp3File {

        NSLog(@"mp3file to play: %@", mp3File ); 

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mp3File, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;

        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        if (audioPlayer == nil) {
            NSLog(@"audio errror: %@",[error description]);
        }
        else {
            [audioPlayer play];
        }
        [audioPlayer release];

        return 0; 
    }   

    @end
```

Here's the calling code:

```
   AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];

   [audioPlayer playAudioFile:@"/A.mp3"];
```

However, when it runs in the separate class, it doesn't successfully create the player and goes to the "audio player == nil" branch

Here's the output:

```
012-07-21 07:14:54.480 MyQuiz[6655:207] mp3file to play: /A.mp3
2012-07-21 07:15:40.827 MyQuiz[6655:207] audio errror: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"
```

The url is "file://localhost/A.mp3"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I somehow have always have trouble when I'm refactoring to separate methods. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in the URL, change this line

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mp3File, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

to this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], mp3File]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out is that you are releasing the audio player immediately after calling play, whereas in the "working" class this does not happen.

A good design to tackle this issue would be to instantiate the audio player once within a Singleton class. This class should be in charge of playing audio across your whole application and should manage any requests from all classes. This way you know you're managing memory correctly and that the AVFoundation framework is used only in one place.

Also, for getting your required path, use:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mp3File] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Comment: I think you're right, releasing was causing a problem. But the other suggested solution for the NSUrl was the one which solved the problem of the invalid string format.

Comment: No prob. Anyways, I recommend using stringByAppendingPathComponent, it's more fit to your needs and is a more generic approach in this matter.